# Changing the filename of a memory mapped file

Tags: linux, mmap

Is it possible to change the name of an already open memory mapped file,
or, do I need to close it, rename it and then mmap it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming a file while it is open is fine, regardless of whether it is mmaped or not.

In UNIX-like systems, the concept of the file itself is distinct from the name (which is called a "link").  A file may have zero, one, or many separate names.  When you have a file open, it is the file itself that you have a reference to - it's OK to change or remove the name (and the file will remain open).

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense because you can mmap a file and close the file descriptor while it's still memory mapped.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yeah renaming it while it's open and/or mmap'd is no problem, it will remain open and mapped. Even if you unlink it, it'll still keep working.